# How do I block access to my local storage

Tags: osx-lion, safari, internet-security

How do I  Block access to my local storage (no cookies/ no storage/ no databases).

- Mac OS X 10.7.2
- Safari 5.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Safari provides you with a Private Browsing mode.

[image]

It explains what that mode will do.

[image]

Please note that DNS entries are still available and their storage can't be prevented.

You can access them with `dscacheutil -cachedump -entries Host`.

You can empty them with `dscacheutil -flushcache`.

**Source:** [How to make Safari’s Private Browsing feature actually private](http://www.switchingtomac.com/tutorials/how-to-make-safaris-private-browsing-feature-actually-private/).